# Android layout screen gets dim like when a dialog is being displayed

Tags: android, layout

I have been facing a strange problem with layout. In my application, there are many layouts for activities and all of them have same background color i.e. grey color. All of those layouts are working as expected in all devices except one layout i.e. in map screen which is slightly different only in case of 4.x devices. The screen appears dim than other screens in 4.x devices. The dimness is like the one when a dialog is being displayed.

Here is layout for the screen:

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <com.readystatesoftware.maps.TapControlledMapView
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:apiKey="@string/mapApiKey"
            android:clickable="true" />

        <TextView
android:id="@+id/uselessTextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:background="@drawable/itemlistbackground"/>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The main problem lies in the framelayout in the above layout. Whenever I set background of the textview with id 'uselessTextView' as a black image i.e itemlistbackground , the screen appearance is Okay.

However,when I remove that textView i.e textview with id uselessTextView, the screen appears slightly dim than usual (Dimness is same like when a dialog is being displayed).

I don't want the black background in above code because placing that textview in above code hides the mapview which is not desired because map is main feature of that activity. but if I do so, the screen gets slightly dim.

Please help me solve the problem.

Comment: Not a good solution but have you tried setting a transparent background inside the useless TextView? Have you tried requesting focus on the mapview somewhere?

Comment: can we have a screenshot?

Comment: Could you try android:background="@android:color/transparent" inside your FrameLayout?